how to implement navigation bar like in youtube in gorouter flutter
to be clear, i dont want to implement the ui itself, but the navigation system
i tried to see some navigation example in flutter documents, but the problem with most of them is that they do not go back to the last main page you visited;
they just close if you go back. i tried to push every route on the page but this introduced a new problem: the stack saves every route i have visited even if its duplcated like i have taped the home page two times i will need to pop 2 times. For example, if I go to home, songs, chat, songs, chat
and then i want to pop it would pop the same like this chat => songs => chat => songs => home instead of chat => songs => home
i think it there must be some implementation to help me but i cant found one and sence im using gorouter i cant use pushandremoveuntil that the navigator provide out of the box
sorry for the long story...
please dont dislike im trying my best
